# mootools. Can't get DOM elements within iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, mootools

I have a site based on SocialEngine 4 which uses moo-tools-1.2.5.
There's an iframe with some js that opens in pop-up (with built-in Smoothbox plug-in). 
And I can't get a DOM element of this iframe from JS included into it just by calling $$(), I've needed to use a kludge like this:

```
var context = (window.frames[0]) ? window.frames[0] : window;
context.$('user_email').set('value', context.$('1_1_30').get('value'));
```

That's strange and I guess that it is unexpected behavior because JS in standard SocialEngine modules don't work within iframes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because in 1.2.5, `$$` is an alias for `this.document.getElements`.

I suggest you use the [IFrame wrapper class](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#IFrame) from mootools-core which can extend iframes so they get mootoolsy, you can then do stuff like:

```
var context = this.document, // window
    iframe = document.getElement("iframe")

// if iframe found, change context to its contentDocument
iframe && (context = new IFrame("foo").contentDocument)

// wrapper.
!function() {
    console.log(this.getElements("div"))
}.call(context)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I've meant that JS code is situated inside of iframe. And I can't understand why it's run in the context of parent instead of it's own.